# the rank of a matrix and its inverse are always equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I had a `true` or `false` quiz in a linear algebra course, one of the statements read

> the rank of a matrix and its inverse are always equal

I answered `true` but the professor said it is `false`, he said that not all matrices have an inverse, but, I tough that since the statement says "and its inverse" it had an inverse since the statement say it; so my question would be, is the statement fine by being false or is it an error in the thinking of the solution of my professor, thanks

Comment: It was a tricky question designed for you to make this mistake. This is not a mathematics question.

Comment: Maybe we can interpret the inverse as *the pseudo-inverse*?

Comment: Short story, you're professor is a troll. Others might disagree, but I believe that saying "and its inverse" implicitly states that there *is* an inverse. Also I disagree of the downvote on this.

Comment: What does "is the statement fine by being false" mean?

Comment: The statement reads "For every $A\in$(matrices), $\text{rank}(A)=\text{rank}(A^{-1})$." Strictly speaking this statement is false because for every $A\in$(matrices) $\text{rank}(A)$ is always number, but $\text{rank}(^{-1})$ doesn't exist sometimes. On the other hand, the following statement is also true: "*Your professor is not a good teacher*."

Comment: @SergioParreiras, I know is more about semantics than mathematics but I believe mathematicians will understand the question from both perspectives :) thanks for the answers

Comment: @user139388, I mean "is the above statement truly false"

Comment: I agree with everyone here and feel OP's pain. Unfortunately, this is exactly the sort of question my PhD adviser likes to ask, pretending the "obvious" mistake is revelatory about the assumptions people make. It's comforting to hear that others agree that such a viewpoint is unproductive.

Answer (score 5):

This is a terrible question as it's more a question about semantics than about mathematics.

There are several reasonable ways of interpreting the question:

A) "Given a matrix $M$, does there exist an inverse of $M$ with rank equal to that of $M$"?

The answer to this question is trivially false; for some matrices the inverse does not exist.

B) "Given a matrix $M$ and its inverse $M^{-1}$, do $M$ and $M^{-1}$ have the same rank?"

This is true, equally trivially: if $M$ has an inverse then it is square and full rank, and $M^{-1}$ likewise.

C) "Given a matrix $M$, does its Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse $M^{+
}$ have the same rank?"

Now *this* is an interesting question; it is worth thinking about why the answer is also "true" (one way to approach it is to look at the SVD of $M$).

Comment: BTW, I think we can see the third point by considering an rwo-reduced echelon matrix.

Comment: If A has a pseudue inverse then the null space of $A^*$ and $A^+$ are the same, right? Then is there a short way to show this (not with blocks..)? @user7530